# Generalize Button(i)_click to get Button(i).text

Tags: c#, listbox, buttonclick

I have the following button_click event which add items to a listbox. Because there are about 30 buttons which text i need to be added to listbox. How i generalize in the form of a function or event so the user click any number button from 1 to 30 should add item  button(i).text to listbox. 
in the following example button1_click add button1.text. i want button(i)_click to add button(i).text to list box where i=1 to 30.
thanks

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Insert(0, " ");

        if ((checkBox_pickup.CheckState != 0) && (checkBox_family.CheckState != 0))
        {
            listBox1.Items.Insert(1, listBox1.Items.Count);
            listBox1.Items.Insert(2, "PICKUP");
            listBox1.Items.Insert(3, textBox2.Text);
            listBox1.Items.Insert(4, textBox1.Text);
            listBox1.Items.Insert(5, "Family");


            listBox1.Items.Insert(5, button1.Text);

            listBox1.Items.Insert(6, DateTime.Now.ToString());
            listBox1.Items.Insert(listBox1.Items.Count, textBox4.Text);
```

Comment: Cast the sender to a Button object, then you have the button's Name and Text property at your disposal: `Button b = sender as Button;`

Answer (score 0):

You should probably write your "own" Button-class (means a class that inherits from Button).

In this class, there should be an ID that has to be set on initialization.

Maybe sounds hard, but actually its a very easy task.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h62478z(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you create your 30 buttons with a code like in the following

```
            Button[] btns=new Button[30];
           for (int ii = 0; ii <30; ii++)
             {
              btns[ii] = new Button();
            //and then you adjust their properties.... 
           // btns[ii].FlatStyle =... 
           // btns[ii].Width = ...
           // btns[ii].Top = ......
            //.......etc
            //
              btns[ii].Tag=ii;
               btns[ii].Click += new EventHandler(presd_btn);
              }
```

Then you can add to that code an EventHandler named e.g. presd_btn
and assign to the button's tag the index e.g. ii (for counting 0,1,,,29) or ii+1 (for counting 1,2,...30).
Then you can access and recognize the button which was pressed by reading its
Tag Number in the presd_btn new click EventHandler.

The EventHandler can be like in the following

```
       private void presd_btn(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
        Button mybutn = sender as Button;
        int btnum=mybutn.Tag;
        listBox1.Items.Insert(0, " ");

       if ((checkBox_pickup.CheckState != 0) && (checkBox_family.CheckState != 0))
       {
        listBox1.Items.Insert(1, listBox1.Items.Count);
        listBox1.Items.Insert(2, "PICKUP");
        listBox1.Items.Insert(3, textBox2.Text);
        listBox1.Items.Insert(4, textBox1.Text);
        listBox1.Items.Insert(5, "Family");

          //and here you assign the pressed button's text
        listBox1.Items.Insert(5, mybtn.Text);

        listBox1.Items.Insert(6, DateTime.Now.ToString());
        listBox1.Items.Insert(listBox1.Items.Count, textBox4.Text);
       //......
       }
```

Hope these help.